# What are the differences between, credentials.helper (to avoid re-enterian account and password) and using SSH keys?

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I would like to know the main differences between storing your credentials with git's credentials.helper locally (to avoiding account and password reiteration) and using SSH key?

Comment: Simply speaking, http/https urls use a username and its password for authentication, and ssh urls use ssh public key and private key. A credential helper helps to cache and provide the username and password, so that the user does not have to manually enter them every time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ElpieKay, following your answer (and just to be sure I fully understand). git credentials.helper store my account and password in cache memory but that does not mean that it's safer than using ssh keys, right? Meaning that, cache stored account and password can be seen by a middle man, am I correct? I just change to SSH anyway, but just wanted to be 100% sure (some traces of OCD) cheers!

Comment: Different credential helpers cache the username and password in different places, in memory, in a plain text file or in a software. As to the safety, I don't know about the details of http(s) and ssh. Some of our machines forbid ssh port for safety reasons (I don't know why).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `git credentials.helper` store my account and password in cache memory but that does not mean that it's safer than using ssh keys, right?

It is different.

First, you won't store your password, but a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), with the [right scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps).
Such token would [start with `ghp_`](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-04-authentication-token-format-updates/) (since Q1 2021).
That way, you keep your password private, and use a token that you can revoke/replace at any time, without losing access to your GitHub account.

The credential helper would be use only for remote URLs starting with `http(s)://`.

For SSH URLs, like `git@github.com:<me>/<myRepo>`, the credential helper would not be used at all.

Only SSH Keys or (since [May 2021](https://github.blog/2021-05-10-security-keys-supported-ssh-git-operations/)) Security Keys (like [Yubikey](https://www.yubico.com/blog/github-now-supports-ssh-security-keys/)) would be used.

Comment: BTW, `credential helper` works for both `https` and `http`, sure u know that.

Comment: @Eric True. HTTP, and port number as well, as illustrated by this [GCM PR](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/pull/825).